# How to write sql COALESCE in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm new to Django. How to write COALESCE sql queryset in to django orm.

```
query = 'SELECT COALESCE(max(CAST(order_no as UNSIGNED)), 0) as o,id from nanossc_Sales_master'
```

models.py

```
class Sales_master(models.Model):
    slno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your model? The above does not look like a valid query, since a `MAX(..)` is usually defined on a set of objects, not a single scalar.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually i am converting PHP query to django. this is php queryset `$result = mysql_query("select COALESCE(max(CAST(order_no AS UNSIGNED)),0) as o from sales_master");`

Comment: @Kumor: than it is an aggregate, but you can not use the `id` then.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem without id its showing error, this is why i used id there

Comment: but in your PHP program, it does not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an [**`Coalesce`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) and [**`Cast`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) here:

```
from django.db.models import Max, PositiveIntegerField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Coalesce

Sales_master.objects.aggregate(
    o=Coalesce(Max(Cast('order_no', output_field=PositiveIntegerField())), Value(0))
)
```

This will produce a dictionary where a key `'o'` maps to the result for this aggregate.