# Django how to get 0 instead of null

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm filtering a query set to get the number of visitors and pageviews but when there is no data it returns None.
How to get 0 instead of None when filtering a queryset when there is no data?

````
yesterday_visitors = queryset.filter(date__gte=yesterday, page=None).aggregate(Sum('visitors'))

yesterday_page_views = queryset.filter(date__gte=yesterday, page=None).aggregate(Sum('page_views')) ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve the same values ​whose data is there or exists and not the rest.In django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547680/retrieve-the-same-values-whose-data-is-there-or-exists-and-not-the-rest-in-djan)

Comment: I actually want to keep None value results but I want them as 0 instead so it doesn't seem _is_null would help here

Comment: You are probably looking for `Coalesce`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444780/5520354

Answer (score 1):

I've finally ended up doing it another way that is probably the easiest one, by just adding "or 0" at the end while use get  __sum on "visitors" and "page_views" :

```
yesterday_visitors = queryset.filter(date__gte=yesterday, page=None).aggregate(Sum('visitors')).get('visitors__sum') or 0

yesterday_page_views = queryset.filter(date__gte=yesterday, page=None).aggregate(Sum('page_views')).get('page_views__sum') or 0
```